# Issues with PHP uploader

Tags: php, forms

I have a simple form which allows the user to store some HTML code, a title, and an image. The form sends the data to PHP which is supposed to store the image (and other non-relevant things.) The images aren't being uploaded, but I am not getting any errors. This tool exists solely to give me a way to add content, and cannot be accessed by anyone else, so I haven't done any checking for input sanitation yet.

HTML:

```
<form id="bpost_form" class="dropzone" method="post" action="writetofile.php" style="text-align:center" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="newpost_title"/>
            <br>
            <input type="file" name="img_upload" id="fileToUpload">
            <br>
            <textarea name="newpost_body" id="newpost" rows="10" cols="80">
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
            <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace('newpost');
            </script>
            <input type="submit"
                   value="Save"/>
        </form>
```

PHP:

```
#Image code
$target_dir = "../BlogPosts/post_images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img_upload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["img_upload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if ($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["img_upload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif") {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_upload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["img_upload"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

Comment: which message is displayed?

Comment: None, that's the main problem.

Comment: Check your error log

Comment: Checked the log, nothing amiss besides something unrelated. Found the problem though, I was just being dumb. A different line in the file was preventing the error from showing -_-, it was just an error with the test file I was using. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

PHP redirected away before the error code could be read. The test image I was using was incorrect, and the redirect prevented me from seeing the correct error code. The problem was solved by removing

```
header('Location: /../index.html');
```

and using a different image.

Comment: That line isn't in any of the code you posted. Next time please post the full code so as to not waste anyone's time.

Comment: I understand, should full code always be posted? Or are there exceptions?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I read through it and will try to better follow guidelines next time.